# How to access services_views the correct way?

Tags: 7, views, services

I am trying to fetch some views with the [services_views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views) module. Sadly enough I keep getting the response: "404: Not found: Display  on view my_view_name could not be found".

I am using [Views 3](http://drupal.org/project/views) and I defined for test a view with a 'page' display id. (default display id is not a "default" anymore)

I know that I have to pass the display_id argument but simply can't make it work.

Here is the calls I am trying to use:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/views/my_view_name.json?display_id="page"
http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/views/my_view_name.json?display_id=page
http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/views/my_view_name.json?parameters[display_id]="page"
http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/views/my_view_name.json?args[display_id]="page"
```

In the resource definition for the service it is clear that display_id has to be passed as an argument.

```
'args' => array(
  'view_name' => array(
    'name' => 'view_name',
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'The name of the view to get.',
    'source' => array('path' => '0'),
    'optional' => FALSE,
  ),
  'display_id' => array(
    'name' => 'display_id',
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'The display ID of the view to get.',
    'source' => 'param',
    'optional' => TRUE,
    'default value' => 'default',
  ),...
```

Is there anyone who managed to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the link http://www.mywebsite.com/rest/views/my_view_name.json?display_id=page is correct one. The problem is you didn't get the correct display_id. Please look in the database in  views_display table.

Answer (score 1):

On a Drupal.org [issue page](http://drupal.org/node/1368036) for this module, someone suggests the following for the 7.x version.

```
The arguments are passed in the usual url format, for example:
http://example.com/my_endpoint/views/view_name?display_id=default&args=123&offset=0&limit=10&return_type=FALSE

Multiple arguments can be used like this:
http://example.com/my_endpoint/views/view_name?display_id=default&args[0]=abc&args[1]=123&offset=0&limit=10&return_type=FALSE
```

I've been trying to get this working on 6.x but haven't succeeded yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Firefox installed, or Firebug you can look at the HTML source to get the display_id. See [this screen shot](http://drupal.org/node/1513348#comment-6113922) (and please ignore my page argument!):

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with services_views to pass arguments to a view called by services request and I solved it by applying a patch in the module without that it won't work.

Here is a diff patch from my project

```
diff --git a/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.moduleb/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.module
index 9ce8080..65dd92e 100755
--- a/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.module
+++ b/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.module
@@ -182,6 +182,10 @@ function services_views_views_plugins() {
 function services_views_services_request_preprocess_alter($controller, &$args, $options) {
   if (isset($controller['view info'])) {
     array_unshift($args, $controller['view info']);
+    $args[0]['args'] = array();
+     if (!empty($_GET['args'])) {
+       $args[0]['args'] = $_GET['args'];
+     }
   }
 }

diff --git a/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.resource.inc b/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.resource.inc
index eb9fbb4..aae2975 100755
--- a/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.resource.inc
+++ b/sites/all/modules/services_views/services_views.resource.inc
@@ -111,10 +111,11 @@ function services_views_execute_view($view_info, $view = NULL, $display_id = NUL
     $view_name = $view_info['view_name'];
     $display_id = $view_info['display_id'];

-    $args = array();
+    $args = $view_info['args'];

     $view = views_get_view($view_name);
     $view->set_arguments($args);
+    $view->execute_display($display_id, $args);
   }
```

I don't remember the link to the patch but that may helps
see [services views args issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/services_views?text=args&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All)

If you created a service display  for the view you would see it as a resource it self.[image]

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you want `display_id=page_1`. The `display_id` parameter must be the **internal** id of the display. AFAIK the default display always has id 'default'.

The id's of any additional page displays you create are not visible in the Drupal 6 UI, but you can find them out by doing an export on your view and looking at the resulting code.

Each display is created with a call to  `$view->new_display()` where the third parameter is the id (see [views_db_object::new_display](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/views_db_object%3a%3anew_display/7)).